# How to get the coordinates of points in polygon in Google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying on [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) tutorial and now i need to get the coordinates of the points of the polygon that i draw here. Please someone explain how can i get the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the

```
drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

I added ​​

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
    // console.log(coordinates);
    window.alert("success"+coordinates);
});
```

Thanks david strachan.